# Getting _detailItem and changing Label data before display

Tags: ios

I have been banging my head against my desk for an hour. I need to get a detail item passed from one view controller to the next, and then update the view before displaying it. For the life of me, I cannot get it to work properly. Here is the code I am using:

VC#1 (passing data from):

```
   -(IBAction)NotOwed:(id)sender{
      InputViewController *input = [[InputViewController alloc]init];
    self.tdModal = input;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    InputViewController *viewController = (InputViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VDI"];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.tdModal setDetailItem:@"NotOwed"];


    // do any setup you need for myNewVC
    [self dismissSemiModalViewController:self];


}

-(IBAction)Owed:(id)sender{


    InputViewController *input = [[InputViewController alloc]init];
        [self.tdModal setDetailItem:@"Owed"];
    self.tdModal = input;


    [input setDetailItem:@"Owed"];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    InputViewController *viewController = (InputViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VDI"];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
       // do any setup you need for myNewVC
 [self dismissSemiModalViewController:self];


}
```

VC#2 (data to):

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

       NSLog(@"THIS: %@", _detailItem);
        [self configureView];

         }

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [oField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [iField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    UIView *fixItView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    fixItView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
    fixItView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //change this to match your navigation bar
    [self.view addSubview:fixItView];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    dueField.inputView = picker;
    [picker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


}
- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        if ([[_detailItem description]  isEqual: @"Owed"]){

            iLabel.hidden = true;
            oLabel.hidden = true;
            mLabel.text = @"owes me the sum of";

        }else{
            iLabel.hidden = false;
            oLabel.hidden = false;

            mLabel.text = @"the sum of";
        }
    }
}
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender
{

     UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)dueField.inputView;


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];



    NSString *editedMoney = [[NSString alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    NSDate *dt = picker.date;
    NSString *dateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:dt];
    dateOwed = YES;
    id delegate = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    if ([_detailItem  isEqual: @"Owed"]) {
    editedMoney = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+$%@", oField.text];

    }else{
       editedMoney = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-$%@", oField.text];

    }
      MasterViewController *topViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];
    topViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSString *wow = [[NSString alloc]init];
    if(oLabel.hidden == true){
        wow = @"someoneowes";
    }else{
        wow=@"nope";
    }
    MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];
    bool OwedYes = dateOwed;
    [master setData:iField.text :editedMoney :picker.date :OwedYes :wow :dateAsString];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


    [UIView beginAnimations:@"LeftFlip" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.view.superview removeFromSuperview];


    NSLog(@"TEH %@", context);
}
```

The NSLog on top of VC#2 reports the proper string, but if I try to use or compare the string, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
InputViewController *input = [[InputViewController alloc]init];
self.tdModal = input;
```

allocates a new `InputViewController` and stores it in the property

but this

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    InputViewController *viewController = (InputViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VDI"];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Allocates another `InputViewController` and displays it.

This

```
[self.tdModal setDetailItem:@"NotOwed"];
```

set the `detailItem` property in the *original* view controller - the one that you haven't displayed.

What you want is

```
-(IBAction)NotOwed:(id)sender{

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
       self.tdModal = (InputViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VDI"];
    [[self presentViewController:self.tdModal animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.tdModal setDetailItem:@"NotOwed"];


    // do any setup you need for myNewVC
    [self dismissSemiModalViewController:self];
}
```

Or, since you are going to dismiss the current VC, you can stick with the local `InputViewController` variable - you need to be consistent and either use the local variable or the property.

Also, if the `InputViewController` is coming from the same storyboard as your current view controller you can link them with a segue and trigger the segue.  You can then set the DetailItem in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: Serious kudos to you! Thanks!

Comment: That's OK.  Sometimes you just can't see it and a fresh pair of eyes spots it straight away